# Why does my 'hello world' Python C module work correctly in everything but IDLE?

Tags: python, c, windows, module, mingw

I compiled a simple hello world C module for Python and it works correctly in everything I've tried but IDLE. Here's what I type to test it:

```
>>> import hello
>>> hello.say_hello('Justin')
```

I have tried this using Python from the command prompt(I'm using Windows), in Eclipse's PyDev, and with PieDream and they all print out `Hello Justin!`.  However, in IDLE it doesn't print anything - it just gives me the prompt.

The module and `setup.py` I'm using are from [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C). I think that the problem is with the compiler.  I'm using MinGW which I set as the compiler for distutils in a .cfg file. I build the module from the command prompt with:

```
python setup.py build
```

and get

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'hello' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win32-2.6
creating build\temp.win32-2.6\Release
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\Python26\PC -c hellomodule.c -o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\hellomodule.o
writing build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\hello.def
creating build\lib.win32-2.6
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\hellomodule.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\hello.def -LC:\Python26\libs -LC:Python26\PCbuild -lpython26 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.6\hello.pyd
```

I'm thinking that it might have something to do with the -mno-cygwin part in there, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas or suggestions as to why this module won't work in IDLE? Should I be using a different compiler?

Comment: This is just a guess, but aren't you supposed to use MSVC++ in Windows for Python?

Comment: @javier You should be able to use just about any c compiler.
As a side note, I followed the tutorial in linux with gcc, and idle does the same thing: no output, but cmd line works, etc. Ok, i just noticed this: if you run idle from command line and run the script, the output is dumped into the terminal window.

Comment: @Javier I've also tried using distutils with it using MSVC++ and get the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the hello is writing directly to `stdout`. Python's `stdout` is not necessarily the the same place as C `stdout`

Normally you would return a string to Python so Python can print it to it's own `stdout`

Comment: Yes, I think that you're right. If I `import sys`, `sys.stdout` is different in IDLE compared to the other places I was running the module. IDLE sets `sys.stdout` to something from the idlelib module.

Comment: @Justin, now to see if you can convert the C string into a Python str and return it :)

Comment: Piece of cake. Onward and upward! Strange that most of the examples I've seen have used printf when apparently it is more appropriate to return a string.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to write to Python's `sys.stdout` from a C-coded extension, you can use something like:

```
void writeout(const char* nullterminated)
{
    PyObject* sysmod = PyImport_ImportModuleNoBlock("sys");
    PyObject* pystdout = PyObject_GetAttrString(sysmod, "stdout");
    PyObject* result = PyObject_CallMethod(pystdout, "write", "s", nullterminated);
    Py_XDECREF(result);
    Py_XDECREF(pystdout);
    Py_XDECREF(sysmod);    
 }
```

(plus, presumably, a little error checking -- just for sanity, in case somebody's done something crazy like `del sys.stdout` &c;-).

Of course, if you need multiple writes, it may be more efficient to get `stdout` only once, keep it around as long as needed, and decref it just once when you're done "printing" stuff (but that won't behave quite right in cases in which your Python caller is reassigning `sys.stdout` while you hold a reference to its previous version: you'll keep printing to the previous version, just like a similarly-behaved Python-coded module would).  This repeated lookup is equivalent to doing `sys.stdout.write(somestring)` in Python, which also looks things up each and every time -- a tad slower but "semantically safer" in case your Python caller is doing "pretty edgy" stuff with `sys.stdout` (as you've found out that IDLE does;-).  ((Not all that edgy, really, so you may want to support it properly;-)).

Comment: I have modified the code to what actually did compile for me, but still gave you +1 because you put me in the right direction of what I had to do.